# Hibernate: just save an entity with @EmbeddedId as primary key

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I wanted to learn hibernate basics and do not understand why my application does not work, when adding an entry to my table using the `@EmbeddedId` annontations for composited primary keys:

Class representing the PK:

```
@Embeddable
public class OHLCVKey implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3996067621138883817L;

    @Column(name="Symbol")
    protected String symbol;

    @Column(name="Currency")
    protected String currency;

    @Column(name="Datum")
    protected java.sql.Date datum;

    public OHLCVKey() {}

    public OHLCVKey(String symbol, String currency, Date datum) {
        super();
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.datum = datum;
    }



    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum(java.sql.Date endTime) {
        this.datum = endTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("OHLCKey: {%s %s %s}", symbol, currency, datum);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (symbol == null ? 0 : symbol.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (currency == null ? 0 : currency.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (datum == null ? 0 : datum.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj != null || !(obj instanceof OHLCVKey)) {
            OHLCVKey other = (OHLCVKey) obj;
            boolean sameSymbol = this.symbol.equals(other.symbol);
            boolean sameCurrency = this.currency.equals(other.currency);
            boolean endTime = this.datum.equals(other.datum);
            return sameSymbol && sameCurrency && endTime;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Persistent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ohlcv_data")
public class OHLCV implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -742762046516249869L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected OHLCVKey key;

    @Column(name = "Exchange")
    private String exchange;

    @Column(name = "Open")
    private double open;

    @Column(name = "High")
    private double high;

    @Column(name = "Low")
    private double low;

    @Column(name = "Close")
    private double close;

    @Column(name = "Volume")
    private long volume;

    public OHLCV() {};

    public OHLCV(OHLCVKey key) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
    }

    public OHLCV(OHLCVKey key, String exchange, double open, double high, double low, double close, long volume) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.exchange = exchange;
        this.open = open;
        this.high = high;
        this.low = low;
        this.close = close;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public OHLCVKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(OHLCVKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getExchange() {
        return exchange;
    }

    public void setExchange(String exchange) {
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }

    public double getOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public void setOpen(double open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

    public double getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public void setHigh(double high) {
        this.high = high;
    }

    public double getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public void setLow(double low) {
        this.low = low;
    }

    public double getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public void setClose(double close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public long getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(long volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
}
```

I assumed that after creating an OHLC instance I could add it's data to my database table with the following function (in a class called `OHLCVDataManager`):

```
public void addOHLCV(OHLCV ohlcv) { // line 50
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(ohlcv); // line 55
        tx.commit();
        log.info("Added {} to database!", key.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        System.exit(2); //TODO remove, exit Spring application
    }
}
```

But I got the following PropertyAccessException/IllegalArgumentException with stack traces:

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [protected OHLCVKey OHLCV.key] by reflection for persistent property [OHLCV#key] : OHLCV@46479254
2018-11-03 18:43:57.567  INFO 18384 --- [       Thread-9] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7582b66f: startup date [Sat Nov 03 18:43:53 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4931)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$StandardGenerationContextLocator.locateGenerationContext(Component.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at OHLCVDataManager.addOHLCV(OHLCVDataManager.java:55)
    at OHLCVDataManager.addOHLCV(OHLCVDataManager.java:70)
    at ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set OHLCVKey field OHLCV
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
```

**EDIT1:**

```
ohlcvDataManager.addOHLCV("TEST", "USD", new java.sql.Date(2018, 1, 1), "TEST", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

// OHLCDataManager#addOHLCV call:    
public void addOHLCV(String symbol, String currency, java.sql.Date date, 
String exchange, double open, double high, double low, double close, long volume) {
    addOHLCV(new OHLCV(new OHLCVKey(symbol,currency, date),exchange, open, high, low, close, volume));
}
```

**EDIT2:** 
I have testet hibernate-core version 5.3.7 and 5.4 with java 1.8

**EDIT2:** 
There is just one OHLCV class and one OHLCVKey class in my classpath, I have also tried to rename the classes.

Comment: What is the hibernate version?

Comment: Does the `OHLCV` definitely have a populated `OHLCVKey` at the point where it is being saved?  Note how `saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId()` is calling `saveWithGeneratedId()` in the stack trace, which suggests it couldn't find a key value.

Comment: Add the code that constructs the instance to be saved.

Comment: @AlanHay see EDIT1

Comment: @df778899 yes see also EDIT1

Comment: Works fine for me. You probably have the key in a different package or something.

Comment: Your `hashCode()` implementation of the PK is probably flawed. You always return `super.hashCode()` instead of `result`. This might be a source for your problem.

Comment: @MicSim it also does not work if I return ´result´

Comment: You should also check the use of the `Date` class. Make sure you don't mix `java.util.Date` with `java.sql.Date`, where it should not be.

Comment: @MicSim I used full path qualifier for java.sql.Date and I think it would not compile if I had mixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to version

> 4.3.11.Final

worked...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hitting a bug with composite keys mapped as EmbededID in hibernate 5.0 and 5.1 It is supposed to be fixed in 5.1.1
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10618

Try changing the hibernate version. Also I can see  in one of the comments that @K.Nicholas is saying that the same code works for him. This is why I am even more inclined to think you are hitting this bug.

Comment: I used 5.3.7, also updating to 5.4 does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I touched hibernate , but from the error it sounds like it is unable to access 
`[protected OHLCVKey OHLCV.key]` this field. To narrow it down, I'd suggest two things. First, see if you can remove the casting in this line `OHLCVKey key = (OHLCVKey) session.save(ohlcv); // line 55` and make it `session.save(ohlcv)`, just to rule out if it is the casting that is causing it or the save itself. Second, although it doesn't make much sense, try if you can change the access modifier here to private.

```
 @EmbeddedId
    protected OHLCVKey key;
```

If any of these two don't help, try using HQL and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set OHLCVKey field OHLCV
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
```

That peace of stacktrace means that Hibernate is trying to set a field value to some object, but their classes are incompatible:

```
protected void ensureObj(Object object) {
    if (!this.field.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
        this.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(object);
    }
}
```

It means that Hibernate has loaded metadata from different class rather than from a class of an object you are trying to save. Please, check if there are only one class OHLCV in the classpath of your application, because example you provided works well.

Comment: There is just one OHLCV class in my classpath, I have also renamed my class.. There are only spring-boot dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

instead of downgrading, I rebuild my Entity to use `@IdClass`

Continuing on the given example, you can remove the @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId annotations. Then you should add on class level for your `OHLCV` the following annotation:

```
javax.persistence.@IdClass(OHLCVKey.class)
```

copy the variables from the `OHLCVKey` class to your `OHLCV` class and add the following annotation **to each of them!**

`@Id`

Then remove the column-annotations from the key-class.
Don't forget that each class needs an Equal's and hashCode implementation!

A small custom example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@IdClass(ExampleCompositeKey.class)
public class Example {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COLUMN_ONE")
    private String something;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COLUMN_TWO")
    private String somethingElse;
    
    @Column(name = "COLUMN_THREE")
    private String regularColumn;
    
    // GETTER's and SETTER's here...
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Example)) return false;
        Example example = (Example) o;
        return Objects.equals(something, example.something)
                && Objects.equals(somethingElse, example.somethingElse)
                && Objects.equals(regularColumn, example.regularColumn);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(something, somethingElse, regularColumn);
    }
}
```

```
public class ExampleCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    private String something;
    private String somethingElse;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ExampleCompositeKey)) return false;
        ExampleCompositeKey that = (ExampleCompositeKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(something, that.something)
                && Objects.equals(somethingElse, that.somethingElse);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(something, somethingElse);
    }
}
```